# Become a Spartan program from movie 300

Tags: programs

When the movie 300 was released, there was a site that promoted a "Become a Spartan" fitness program. I believe it was an 8 or 16 week program where the intensity increased a lot each week.
I can't find that site anymore though, only some sites with rip-off programs or paid programs.
Does anyone still have this program or know where I can find it?

Comment: Not to be a naysayer, but it will take a lot longer than 8 to 16 weeks to "look like a spartan"

Comment: I'm just wondering about where to find the program...I'll make it work :p

Answer (score 2):

[Spartan Workout](http://www.menshealth.com/fitness/muscle-building-11) courtesy of Mens Health magazine.

**THE BEGINNER 300 WORKOUT**

- Body-Weight Rows - 15 reps
- Body-Weight Squats - 25 reps
- Pushups - 15 reps
- Jumping Jacks - 50 reps
- Mountain Climbers - 20 reps
- Close-Grip Pushups - 10 reps
- Body-Weight Rows - 15 reps

**THE INTERMEDIATE 300 WORKOUT**

- Pullups - 25 reps
- Dumbbell Deadlift - 50 reps
- Pushups - 50 reps
- Body-Weight Squat Jumps - 50 reps
- V-Ups - 50 reps
- Dumbbell Push Press - 50 reps
- Pullups - 25 reps

**THE "ORIGINAL" 300 WORKOUT**

- Pullups - 25 reps
- Barbell Deadlift with 135 lbs. - 50 reps
- Pushups - 50 reps
- 24-inch Box Jumps - 50 reps
- Floor Wipers - 50 reps
- Single-Arm Clean-and-Press with 36 lbs Kettlebell - 50 reps
- Pullups - 25 reps

The article includes video demonstrations of the exercise. Discussion of the workouts [here](http://www.gymjones.com/knowledge/article/300/) indicate that the above may have been a [testing mechanism](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/the-300-workout-can-you-handle-it?page=2), something which was timed to figure out where the actors were in the process. Here's [another version](http://www.popworkouts.com/gerard-butler-300-workout/?PageSpeed=noscript), cribbed from various accounts to break it down day by day (it's a bit too extensive for me to post quotes, but it's a mixture of weightlifting and cardio that seems high on the "Crossfit" aspects). Overall, I really get the impression that it was whatever Mark Twight felt was right at the moment. There's a lot of "do this to exhaustion" to push people to their limits.

Comment: +1 for directly answering in full format and posting a link the source.

Comment: My pleasure. I vaguely remembered reading it in the magazine in the workout center at my old apartment. I started out with just the link, but I wanted to avoid link rot.

Comment: Thanks, but I found that one already. I was more looking for the actual website which had a different program...the Men's Health program does not talk about incremental training per week.

Comment: {nods} What I've found so far doesn't sounds like there were many increments. Twight speaks again about it in http://www.gymjones.com/knowledge/article/300/ where the same set of exercises as above are cited. The only one I've found that mentions progression is http://www.popworkouts.com/gerard-butler-300-workout/?PageSpeed=noscript, which breaks it out by day.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that Gym Jones is Twight's gym, so that's the most authoritative source I've found so far.